# Pre-populate Gmail with HTML body (pictures + formatting)

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I'm wondering, is it possible to pre-populate Gmail body with HTML elements such as pictures, formatting directly from the Gmail client?

Currently there are some canned responses, but they don't interact well with our custom customer individual data.

The questions is not so much around email, subject line, and non-formatted body text—these can achieved using the URL hack. However, I’m looking for something more robust.